# Problem downloading 10.8. Can I use my copy?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am helping a friend with his computer. He purchased 10.8 through the AppStore. However, the internet at his location is iffy at best, and we've tried for days to download with no success. Can I use my own saved copy to install on his system, or will we run into update issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no update issues.

Answer (score 1):

It will download the components required for that specific Mac, which doesn't take long and will ask for his AppleID.
So yes.

Comment: Please clarify. "Yes" meaning it will be ok? or "Yes" he will run into problems? Thanks

Comment: Haha oh sorry. Yes it'll be fine. If you need any help with the process, just ask :)

Answer (score 1):

No problems so long as he enters his apple id, on which you've also purchased ML, in at installation.